# Reverse proxy using nginx on bluehost vps does not works with subdomains

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have bluehost VPS hosting on which I am hosting a node js app. I have configured my vps server and installed nginx on it. Now I am using the reverse proxy to redirect the domain.com to `localhost:3000` which is running node js app. Now I have a second node js app that I want to run on sub.domain.com which is running on `localhost:3001`. I created the subdomain on bluehost then used the same reverse proxy config for `sub.domain.com` but it is not working.

[image: Configuration of domain.com for 1st node app which is working fine]

and

[image: Configuration of sub.domain.com for 2nd node app which is not working] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but adding

"proxy_redirect http://localhost:3001 http://sub.domain.com;"

in configuration file of subdomain fixed my problem :)

[Solution Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynJty.png)